# how to collect custom data from 3 table in database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

#### i have 3 table - first one about supplier details second one about payment for supplier   third one orders

all of them have relationship

table payment for supplier include 3 column for three date for payment with 
  amount in ever date

#### the question is   how to collect date from three table like that:

---

the header of table


supplier name 

first date (month)

> from payment date in database

second date

> from payment date in database

---

table contain

    first supplier  -  [sum ] amount for first date  -  [sum ] amount for second date

  second supplier  -  [sum ] amount for first date  -  [sum ] amount for second date

**and this for all supplier**

how to do that??

Comment: are you looking for the SQL statement that you need to get the data?  I would recommend making an attempt to write it yourself and we can help you fine tune it.  This looks like it will be a pretty basic SQL join statement.

Comment: yes i looking for SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

select 
sup.suppliername, pay.firstdate, pay.seconddate
from suppliers sup
left join payments pay
on sup.supplierid = pay.supplierid

or somthing like that?